# Iterating over HashSet with for each

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I'm trying to iterate over the Integer objects of a `HashSet` and I want to count the number of times an element occurs. this is my method so far

```
public int freq(int element) {
    int numElements = 0; 

    for (int atPos : mySet){ 
       if (mySet.atPos == element){ //says atPos cannot be resolved to a field
          numElements++; 
       }
    }
    return numElements;
}
```

would it be better to use an iterator to iterate over the elements? How do I fix my

```
mySet.atPos
```

line?

This is where I initialize my `HashSet`

```
   private HashSet <Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Comment: uhm, your `atPos` is the integer from the set that you have gathered. Assume that your set contains `3, 2, 111`, then you have three loops where `atPos` is  `3`, `2` and finally `111`. So just do `if (atPos == element)`

Comment: Your issue is a simple misunderstanding of how you can use variables. `int atPos` and `mySet.atPos` do not refer to the same thing. The former refers to a local variable, the latter is looking for a public member of field of an instance of a set *called the same thing*.

Comment: but ... do you realize that you will always get either 0 or 1 as result of your `freq(...)` function? That's how sets works ...

Comment: @KarelG why will I always get 0 or 1? Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: @emmynaki sets never contain duplicates.  Lists can, but sets will automatically delete duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a simple misunderstanding of how you can use variables. `int atPos` and `mySet.atPos` do not refer to the same thing. The former refers to a local variable, the latter is looking for a public member of field of an instance of a set called the same thing.

You are trying to access this field:

```
public class HashSet
{
    public int atPos; //<<<
}
```

but, when we think of it this way, obviously that field does not exist in `HashSet`!

All you need to do is get rid of `mySet.` and your code will work.

```
if (atPos == element){
    numElements++; 
}
```

> Would it be better to use an iterator to iterate over the elements?

No, there's no benefit to using an iterator in this situation. A for each is more readable.

---

As others have noted, because sets will never contain duplicates, your `numElements` will actually only ever be one or zero. As such, you could actually write your function very compactly as:

```
public int freq(int element) {
    if (myset.contains(element)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or even better using the ternary operator:

```
public int freq(int element) {
    return myset.contains(element) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) cannot contain duplicate elements. Therefore you will always get a count of 0 or 1 for your `element`.

For any collection, you can get the frequency of the elements with:

```
public int freq(int element) {
    return Collections.frequency(mySet, element);
}
```

Not sure you'd want to make a method out of it ...